# JavaScript Not Displaying Compiled Text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put together a little script to save some typing for some stuff we type repetitively at my office. Basically the idea is that you select a couple options and then the page displays a paragraph inserting some of the selected custom text at various places.

Anyways, this is what I have, and it isn't working. I've tried putting some console.logs in the JavaScript, and they aren't doing anything. Why?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script>

    function write() {
        var name1 = document.getElementById("firstname");
        var name = name1.options[name1.selectedIndex].text;
        var gender1 = document.getElementById("gender");
        var gender = gender1.options[gender1.selectedIndex].text;
        var authentication1 = document.getElementById("authentication");
        var name = authentication1.options[authentication1.selectedIndex].text;

    var answer = name + gender + authentication; // There will be some other text added in here           eventually

    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += answer;
        }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Name"><br /><br />

    <select name="gender">
    <option value="his">His</option>
    <option value="her">Her</option>
    </select><br /><br />

    <select name="authentication">
    <option value="questions">security questions</option>
    <option value="firstyear">first year attended</option>
    <option value="birthday">birthday and mailing address</option>
    </select><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="write(); return false;">
    </form>

    <h2 id="text"></h2>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: the JS function `write();` is being executed `onSubmit` which means at submit time but the form is empty before hand.  I think you need something like `onBeforeSubmit` which is IE only (so don't use it) or another button to generate the text before submit

Comment: you also have a few typos in your JS... let me see if I can come up with a quick fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write is a method of document. It will never work, it will just paint a blank page

```
function writeThis() {
   var name = document.forms[0].firstname.value;
   var gender = document.forms[0].gender.options[document.forms[0].gender.selectedIndex].text;
   var authentication = document.forms[0].authentication.options[document.forms[0].authentication.selectedIndex].text;
   document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += (name + "  " + gender + "  " + authentication);
}
```

I renamed your function as `writeThis()` so make sure in your html :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="writeThis();return false">
```

Also, the new function show you how to get the values. Review it that way you learn how to do it. Finally, it's a better practice if you close always your html tags `<input />` not `<input>`.

And the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xr7vqsfm/4/

Comment: Good Coding Verhaeren, but why is the / better practice ? The / in what they call VOID elements, HTML5 ( the doctype on the OP's question ) specs say  "Optionally, a "/" character, which may be present only if the element is a void element."[W3 Specs, HTML5 void element ](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html#void-element).

Comment: The browser will render <input> and <input /> the same, but let's say you want to store some html in an xml file so you can parse the file later, <input> then will throw a parsing error. If you look at the fiddle in my answer you will see that </form> is higlighted in red. That's because the <input>. Close those tags and the red color on </form> will dissapear. The browser will render well everything but you never know what you are going to do with your code and you might find yourself in an escenario that the closing tag is mandatory.